# Why do some Trello actions consistently fail inside my work firewall?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

When I use Trello at work, certain specific actions consistently fail to get persisted back to the server.  The two that I am always having issues with are:

- Removing labels
- Deleting items from checklists

As an example, let's say I create a new card and assign label **A**.  I then come back later and remove label **A**, but assign label **B**.

The outcome is at first an orange message in the top right corner:

> Sending...

This is followed by a red message in the top right corner:

> Connection interrupted.  Retrying 1 action.

This message never goes away.  If I refresh Trello, the card will have both labels **A** and **B** assigned.

My workaround at the moment is to open the Android app on my phone and remove the label.

I'm guessing this is related specifically to our work environment - the firewall, proxy, ISA server, etc.  I have tried using Fiddler to see which specific HTTP requests are failing, but as soon as Fiddler is hooked in as a proxy all external web sites stop working.

My question is, does anyone know what is special about these specific actions and why they might be failing inside my work firewall?

*Note - I don't believe this a bug in Trello as it works perfectly outside of work!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of the actions you described use the `DELETE` HTTP verb. Is your proxy blocking non-`GET`/`POST`/`PUT` requests?

Other things that use `DELETE`, for testing if this is in fact the root issue:

- Removing a member from a card
- Deleting a card
- Removing a member from a board
- Removing a vote from a card (requires the voting powerup to be enabled)

Comment: I think you've got it.  I hardly ever delete cards, and don't really use members,  so wouldn't have noticed these.  I just added a member to a card successfully, and removing it threw up the same error!  I'll see if our proxy can be changed.

Comment: Our sysadmins have enabled an SSL tunnel through our proxy, and everything now works flawlessly.  Thanks for your answer (and keep up the great work with Trello!)